# Xcode 5 app submission issue

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, submit, mac-app-store

Some days ago I installed Xcode 5. Today I'm trying to submit an app, but during validation I'm getting this issue: "The network connection was lost". I've never had any problem with Xcode 4.

My network is OK and I'm not using any proxy.

What is causing this problem?

Comment: I am having the same issue since some hours. Before, also with Xcode 5, everything worked fine so I think that it's a temporary problem with the Apple servers.

Comment: Same here in Sweden, so the issue seems to be their end and what the message says. Good that I found this so I can stop trying all sorts of things, too bad the upload server is down :'(

Comment: Same problem in London. I'm trying to upload 10 apps. Tryed more than 50 times... only 2 builds finally uploadeds. I've got the problem with Xcode 4.6.3 :(

Comment: Same here in Düsseldorf, Germany. I tried the validate process for more than hour with no success. :-(

Comment: Same issue here in France, whereas we submitted 10 apps on Saturday. Probably a heavy traffic issue.

Comment: Same here in Sweden.I was able to upload an archive successfully yesterday and today, I have been trying for like 4 hours and my validation always fails with network connection lost.I am even facing problem in posting iMessages.

Comment: Finally is working NOW

Comment: Working now in France at 6:00 AM CEST

Comment: Working here again. (6:50 AM CEST)

Comment: Working here in Italy too. Thanks to all!

Comment: I am having the same issue, tried rebooting, quit Adobe Application Manager still no luck.

Answer (score 93):

It might have been a coincidence, but like other recent xcode issues I solved this by restarting xcode.

Comment: thanks, a typical solution to many software problem, have you tried to turn it off and on again :)

Comment: It didn't work for me. Should i create a new archive for submission?

Comment: because it seems like a single symptom gazillion causes kind of issue. not even rebooting freaking osx fixed this for me. that's why it's probably not accepted. As for the rebuilding the ipa I doubt that's gonna fix anything, it seems to be broken server-side this time around

Comment: This fixed it. Using Xcode 6.3.1, seems Apple could have fixed this by now if they cared.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was to submit the app via Application Loader (downloadable directly from iTunes Connect) rather than Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I have the observation that with Mavericks and App Nap enabled, a hidden Organizer window within XCODE will cause the network connection to be dropped.

Even if the window is occulated (hidden) for just a second).

Make sure the window is always visible and the problem does NOT occur.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about your luck because you can't control Apple's Server's traffic problem, We all merely become the victim of that..So cut the long story short...

By restarting may work but everyone as in my case, i tried by restarting XCODE, SYSTEM, ROUTER and anything and everything possible, only error name had changed from "The network connection was lost" to "The request timed out" and vice Versa..!

Again i googled for that error some more solution i have found so i thought it may help further seekers.

Here,
[XCode 5 hangs with a timeout error when validating/uploading a "ready to be uploaded" app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512877/xcode-5-hangs-with-a-timeout-error-when-validating-uploading-a-ready-to-be-uplo)

PS: Only perseverance can help you in this way..keep redialing..And WAIT and WATCH:P

Comment: ... and call Apple and vent

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. I submitted app through Application Loader and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

For me the issue seemed to be related to the Adobe Application Manager which was trying to update CS6 but was stuck.  I rebooted the computer and restarted the Adobe update and the instant I did that xcode started the upload.

Comment: how the Adobe Application Manager creates problem with app submission from xcode?