# XCode 5 hangs with a timeout error when validating/uploading a "ready to be uploaded" app

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I've been developing and uploading apps for some months. Whenever they needed being uploaded to the app store, I could do it without problem, but now, I'm stuck with one that doesn't want to be validated/uploaded. XCode says "the request timed out" after MANY minutes with a spinwheel on screen.

The differences between my old updates to the app store and the one I'm trying right now are:

-Xcode 4.X before, Xcode 5 now.

-I had to recreate the app store certificate/provisioning profiles, because they just expired.

-I inherited this project from other coworker (not here anymore) and maybe my "developer profile" is somewhat conflicting with some certificates, etc... (Still many dark areas for me).

I've kind of tried "everything". Erasing provisioning/profiles, closing Xcode, resetting, cleaning my project. But no luck. My current Xcode 5 is able to compile my app perfectly, I'm even able to select the distribute option before uploading (the app is ready to be uploaded onto itunes connect), I even login with my client credentials onto itunes connect, I can even select the correct provisioning profile (app store profile, not a developer one), but no luck:

If I choose to upload or validate, Xcode just complains with some kind of "dull" timeout error.

Any hints? Any way to debug what happens behind the curtains?

Greetings, I'm at a loss.

EDIT: Apparently, the timeout failing event appears in the validation process. If I try to upload, the status log says "Failed Validation". If I try to validate, obviously there's also a "Failed validation" error. Where can I find some log to see what part of the validating process is failing?

Comment: I got the same issue few days ago, Apple server might be saturated, just try again latter

Comment: I don't think so, EVERY time I've been trying to validate, the process failed. At least for 24 h. I doubt it's a server problem... Apparently, everything is OK: http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

Comment: the system status page does not include itunesconnect servers, on sunday I have tried something like 10 times to upload 3 updated apps of 40MB each. After the first failures I gave up uploading through wifi and used the old good ethernet cable, it was better but I still got issues. What is the size of your application ?

Comment: look at https://devforums.apple.com/message/899065#899065, also for developer there is another status page https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/

Comment: Its size is 42 MB. Nothing TOO big. I'm connected to an ethernet cable onto an otherwise working LAN/Internet environment.
According to these 2 new links, the status one shows everything green. The other link doesn't work because I haven't activated my developer account for the forums, but I'll do it right now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Well, that's just a list of people with apparently the same problem I have, but no clear solution. I'm not aware of any changes on my company ISP/firewall policies, which are quite relaxed anyway. I'll try something with netstat and similar tools.

Comment: "traceroute origin-itunesconnect.apple.com" apparently never reaches its destiny... After some hops, it just prints * * * many times... Maybe my problem is as mundane as that...

Comment: I get the same traceroute. That doesn't mean the server's down though does it? It just means it can't find a route through the network? Any way to force it to work using a proxy or something?

Comment: It's very common for some network nodes to not respond to ping or traceroute (each star means an attempt with no response).  You know they're still forwarding traffic, though, if you get responses from nodes further away later in the trace and that's what's important.  I'm getting this problem immediately after XCode said it had to download some new credentials which makes me suspicious that this could be the core of the problem (for me, anyway).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, apparently: "Problem solved".

After 2 boring days trying to upload my app (via Xcode 5, and via Application Loader), I've discovered that Apple upload servers seem to be overloaded (unless a better explanation arises).

I'm in Europe, and from 9 to 14 h my app was ALWAYS rejected. But once I tried it after 16h, the upload and validation processes worked like a charm (both with Xcode 5 and with Application Loader).

Why this? No idea, but I didn't change anything in my upload process, so it's sad, but the solution is:
"Have patience, and wait to upload your app on a time slot where Apple upload servers are not overloaded". The sad part is: No one knows WHEN is that time :)

Comment: Just been trying continually between 4pm and 5.30pm, and now at 11.30pm (GMT) and still no luck. Not very happy!

Comment: It's happening for me too, so I think there must be some server issues right now.

Comment: Same here, problems uploading my app for the past 18 hours

Comment: Global Corporation quality servers, huh.

Answer (score 13):

I solved it by switching Internet provider.

I simply connected my laptop to my iPhone via Personal Hotspot and used LTE network to upload the app.

It worked for me twice.

Comment: Just worked for me.  I tried two wifi access points and restarted machine and Xcode.  No luck.  Then switched to hotspot using ATT and Samsung Android and uploaded on the first try.

Comment: Same thing here. Tried connecting through a VPN after tearing off my hair for an entire day and voila. Everything working smoothly... Thanks for the tip! And thanks one more time for making our lives so miserable, Apple.

Comment: I can't believe. I made a Hotspot via my iPhone and it worked! Thanks

Comment: I didn't believe this until I witnessed it with my own eyes.  Two days of restarts (XCode, Mac, routers, etc.) and then both Validate and Submit succeeded first time after connecting Bluetooth through my Nexus 5...  which uses the same provider as my home cable/internet.  I _really_ don't get why this made a difference but it did!

Comment: Is that an issue of net neutrality gone wrong then?

Answer (score 6):

for Xcode 13 and Mac OS Big Sure

1. Install the "Transporter" app from the MacOS app store.
2. From Xcode's organizer, select your archive and press "Distribute App"
3. Instead of "Upload", select "Export" and proceed as usual.
4. Drop the exported .ipa into the transporter and press "Deliver".

Comment: Thanks for sharing man. You just saved me a lot of time.

Comment: This is a great alternative way to upload app to the app store, but in my case still required changing the internet connection (switched to my phone's hotspot and tried several times).

Answer (score 1):

In my case I changed the dns server from my provider to the google dns server (8.8.8. and 8.8.4.4).

I think you can try any other, if your providers dns or what ever doesn't work

Comment: Yess! I appended 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to my mac's ethernet DNS IPs and it works without switching to exclusively wifi! For months, previous errors were "failed: codesign - A timestamp was expected but not found" and "There was an error connecting to the Apple ID server". Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Faced the error many times, not sure why.

Try this

1. Export the ipa after the archive

[image]

1. Add and upload in Transporter

I get 100% success in uploading and feel a little quicker than Xcode's upload.

Answer (score 0):

I actually called Apple Developer Support about this and they solved the problem!

It turned out that my recovery email address in my Apple ID (not the main email address but the recovery one) was not verified. They had me go to http://appleid.apple.com, login with my Apple ID, and then go to the 'Password and Security' section (on the left).

After answering my security questions I was able to resend the verification email, and once verified I was able to log in on Xcode straight away!

Answer (score -1):

I have the observation that with Mavericks and App Nap enabled, a hidden Organizer window within XCODE will cause the network connection to be dropped.

Even if the window is occulated (hidden) for just a second).

Make sure the window is always visible and the problem does NOT occur.

Comment: Occurs even if window is visible all the time.

Comment: I retract my observation... now the same as occurred to me today trying to upload three apps.  Only restarting Xcode solved the issue for each upload.  Sorry for the misleading information.