# App Store submission/distribution error "failed to open ssh session"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, app-store

I'm trying to submit an iOS PhoneGap app to the app store via Xcode 5.0.2 but I'm encountering problems at the final distribution stage. The app works perfectly on the simulators and devices that I've used and even passes the validation yet when I go to distribute it a number of errors pop up and the project's status is listed as "Failed Validation".

[image]

I've had no luck searching for these errors on-line and I don't understand how it passes validation when I click validate but somehow fails it when I go to distribute.

I see other Xcode submission problems are linked to [Apple server traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096621/xcode-5-app-submission-issue) but I'm not getting any "network connection lost" errors.

I've seen some issues requiring a Java update for Xcode but they seemed to effect Xcode 4 and I'm using Xcode 5.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I'm using an iMac on a University network.

Comment: have you fixed the problem? I've having the same issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue currently and there are definitely no network issues on my end. I have a feeling this is an issue on Apples' side of things.

Comment: Hi Kernix and Ophychius. I haven't fixed the problem yet unfortunately. I'm after getting new errors as well related to connecting to SOCKS proxy. What I think the problem is at the moment is that I'm using Macs on a university campus and I believe that the college network may be preventing me from uploading. I should no if this is the case in a few days and will edit the question once I find out.

Answer (score 7):

After having the same issue I've been able to fix this issue.

To solve this issue you need to:

Go to page 6 "System and Network Requirements" from https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

verify that all of the ports and IP addresses are accessible.

After opening all of the ports from the table, I'm now able to upload my apps.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that I was using a university network which has a number of restrictions on servers as well as uploading and downloading. The only fix for this problem was to find another Mac to use which wasn't restricted.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to do what @kernix suggests, make sure your bitching corporate firewall isn't trying to mug you off. Are your ports open?

Another solution is to user Application Loader instead.

Open Application Loader, got to preferences (⌘+,) and unselect Signiant and Aspera, but leave DAV selected.

[image: Application loader preference]