# Mac OS X vmware guest 'failed to open ssh session. (16)' when using Application Uploader

Tags: macos, ssh, app-store, vmware, application-loader

I have been trying to upload an iOS app to Apple App Store for almost a week without success. The last of the series of problems I am faced is the persistent SSH connection error from Application Uploader.

```
The session's status is FAILED and the error description is
'failed to open ssh session. (16).'
```

Have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288516/app-store-submission-distribution-error-failed-to-open-ssh-session) but I don't have a Mac - only a vmware guest Mac OS. Would be grateful if anyone can point me towards a fix. Is this a problem with VM machine settings. Firewall? Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You can try this guide to enable SSH http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_enable_ssh_your_mac. I suggest using a Bridged Network for your Vmware Guest and manually Add a static IP address For your Guest OS above the DHCP range, using Network setup. For example if you connect to your Router find DHCP in your LAN settings and it will show you the range, ie 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.100. So choose 192.168.0.101 for your Mac IP. Heres a Guide to do that too http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22161/how-to-set-up-a-static-ip-in-mac-os-x/.

Comment: You would likely have better luck with this question at superuser or related stackexchange networks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having the same issue I've been able to fix this issue.

To solve this issue you need to:

Go to page 6 "System and Network Requirements" from https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

verify that all of the ports and IP addresses are accessible.

After opening all of the ports from the table, I'm now able to upload my apps.

Enjoy!